# Using callback defined in different file gives "Undefined reference"

Tags: c, callback

I am trying to use a callback function. This has worked fine when the caller and the called function were in the same file. I have lately decided to make the called function part of a library, so I have it declared in a header file, defined in its own file. I #include the new header in the calling source file, linking to the new library, and now I get an "Undefined reference" error to the callback function.

Is there something special I have to do to make this work? I notice when I use the same thing in pthread libraries for example, the callback function is defined as a pointer function.

Edit: I am linking to the library, and I can call other functions in the library just fine.

Comment: I am linking with the library containing the callback

Comment: Is the callback maybe declared `static`?

Comment: No, if it is to be callable from outside, it mustn't be `static`. If declared `static`, it wouldn't be visible, no symbol exported. So, does `nm yourlib | grep callback_name` give any hints?

Comment: I didn't know that function existed. I ran it on my library containing the callback, and the callback shows up.

Comment: This is strange - thought it was related to the fact that it is a callback parameter somehow, but I just changed the callback to another function in the library and it compiles fine - it's just the actual callback function causing the problem

Comment: Ah - found the problem - egg on my face! There were two definitions of the callback in the header file, one static, one not. I dont know why that was allowed to compile, but that was causing the other problem. if you want to write up an answer I'll accept

Comment: What was the grep output? Was it something like `U callback_name` or `00000432 T callback_name` or something else?

Comment: it was like 000000006cd9 t callback_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was my header had the definition in  there twice, one with static, one without.

Answer (score 2):

Possible problems:

1. the definition of the function (in the .c file) does not coincide with its declaration (in the .h file) and the code using this function essentially tells the linker to go and find what's in the header file and not what's actually in the library.
2. you have forgotten to compile the file implementing the function or put the resulting object file into the library and so the linker can't find the function in the library.
3. you have some source files open and unsaved and while they look fine and complete in the editor, their on-disk contents is different and something is amiss when you try to compile the code.
4. you are having some issues with `make` (bad makefile?) making it think that either the file implementing the function does not need to be compiled or it has already been compiled and needs no recompilation. Fixing the makefile and/or deleting the object and library files will fix the problem.
5. you have mixed C and C++ code and are having issues because of C++ name mangling. Using `extern "C" { }` may help here.
6. you have defined that function as `static` and so it's invisible in other modules (.c files) at link time. Removing `static` will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the actual code that implements the callback, including a header isn't enough.

So, it sounds as if your application needs to link to the library, which it of course already should be doing in order to call functions in the library.

Comment: Edited question to include that I am linking. I can call other functions in the library fine.